# Repetir la funcion X cantidad de veces

Tags: python

estoy tratando de parsear un json con python ya tengo todo terminado... pero el problema es que tengo que repetir MUCHISIMAS veces la misma funcion cambiando un parametro en este caso un numero consecutivo...

```
import urllib.request
import json
import mysql.connector

x = 1

for i in range (10):
    x = x + 1

    url = 'https://url.com/user.aspx?tipo=96&num='+str(x)+'&sexo=M'
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)

##parsing response
    r = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
    cont = json.loads(r.decode('utf-8'))

    print(cont['usuario']["denominacion"])
```

si yo ingreso directamente en `https://url.com/user.aspx?tipo=96&num= 123 &sexo=M` por ejemplo, lee el json, toma los datos, los parsea y los guarda en mi base de datos. Yo necesito hacer eso mismo con el 123, 124, 125, 126 y asi en un rango determinado de números.

así como lo tengo, que obviamente lo que falla es el bucle del a X, me tira el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "afip.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(cont['usuario']["denominacion"])
KeyError: 'usuario'
```

si elimino esto

```
x = 1

for i in range (10):
    x = x + 1
```

y de la url esto: `+str(x)+` y pongo un numero fijo... todo funciona sin problemas...

Como puedo hacer que se repita?

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: La indentación de tu código es tal cual se ve en esta pregunta? O ha sido un problema del cortapega? Te pregunto en particular porque creo que todas las líneas después de `x=x+1` deberían estar indentadas para estar dentro del bucle ¿no? ¿no era esa tu intención?

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder! Lo olvide, ahi agregando la indentación, me tira error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "afip.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(cont['usuario']["denominacion"])
KeyError: 'usuario'

Comment: Ese error no dice que tires todo a la izquierda pues, como dice @abulafia, eso tiene pinta de necesitar estar dentro del bucle (es decir, un nivel a la derecha). Lo que pasa es que, si en una parte usas tabulaciones y en otra espacios, tira el error que ves. Debes asegurar que siempre indentes las líneas usando lo mismo, sea tabs o sea espacios. Recuerda que puedes editar la pregunta e ir indicando qué más pruebas y qué resulta.

Comment: Hola Alfabravo, si ya edite, me habia confundido ahora me sigue tirando el mismo error estando con la indentacion

Comment: Actualizo: descubri que es porque en el numero 2 que es el primer chequeo que hace... justo en ese numero no hay nada por eso tira el error... así que meti todo dentro de un try: y un except KeyError: y listo... todo funcional... Mil gracias a ambos <3